# Many non-native speakers pronounce 'azure' like 'Asia' or like 'essure' when naming Microsoft's product Azure - wrong pronunciation or am I mistaken?

Tags: pronunciation, non-native-english

I live in Austria and I am a student in computer science and there is a specific thing that drives me bonkers:

Every time when a person in my vicinity or I am conversing with is mentioning the product "Microsoft Azure", they pronounce the word *Azure* /ˈeɪʒə/ (like *Asia*) or /ˈeʃə/ (like *pressure* without the initial *pr*).

What is so odd is that not only users of this product or students pronounce it that way, but also representatives from MS who promote this product. So far the representatives I have met have all been non-native English speakers, though.

Sometimes I have corrected the person in such a conversation and telling them it is pronounced /ˈazjʊə/ (like *sure* with an *a* the beginning and replacing the *s* with a *zh* sound. [It is pronounced that way on Leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Azure), a commonly used online dictionary.

The primary proof I bring forward however in such a case is the song [*Rule, Britannia!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zk7OGfvHHhw), in which the word *azure* is pronounced /azjʊə/ like I mentioned.

**My question is:** Am I right that everyone who pronounces the name *Azure* like *Asia* or *essure* pronounces it incorrectly, or have I missed anything when learning the English language and I am just plain stupid? Or does the Microsoft product have a different pronunciation to the regular word *azure*?

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/azure) agrees with your pronunciation.

Comment: Azure wie Journal.

Comment: Thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet for findig the duplicate thread! To be honest, I did not search for a thread about this topic as I thought that my question is so awkwardly special, that nobody has evr asked this - I was wrong. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Let's agree on a few notations:

`/s/` - regular "s" sound. the same sound in "The united **s**tate**s**"
`/z/` - regular "z" sound. the same sound in "**Z**ebra" 
`/ʒ/` - "french J" sound, the same sound as in "vi**s**ion" 
`/ʃ/` - the same sound as in "**sh**ame" and "**sh**allow"

At least for **American English** , Merriam-Webster, Macmillan and Wiktionary (which shouldn't be disregarded!) all agree that "azure" should be pronounced with the `/ʒ/` sound ("french j).

for British English, dictionaries vary, but it seems that the British pronunciation has the /z/ or /ʒ/ sounds, but never the /s/ or /ʃ/ sounds.

Comment: The question is quite clear: he’s saying that most people he encounters in Austria pronounce it /eɪʒər/ _or_ /eʃər/. The fact that the ⟨s(i)⟩ in _Asia_ is pronounced differently from the ⟨ss⟩ in _pressure_ is part of the description.

Comment: well, it sounded to me as if he thinks the s in Asia is pronounced the same way as in Pressure, hence the misunderstanding.

Comment: German does not have an /æ/ vowel, and consequently many German speakers pronounce _azure_ with a mid front vowel /e:/ instead of a low front vowel /æ/. The problem for German speakers is perhaps worst with the English word _jazz_ /ʤæz/. German does not allow /ʤ/ at the beginning of words, nor /z/ at the end, so there are endless variations, since jazz is very popular in the German-speaking world. Haj Ross tells me that old jazzmen don't care at all, and just pronounce it as if it were a German word: /yats/.

Comment: Would have given you a +1, but for the Wiktionary. You came out with a 0!

Comment: Wiktionary is a great dictionary if you want to speak like a native speaker and not how some fancy English professors from the UK want you to sound.